# Postgres import data optimization

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres question :

I have a database with a table which contains weeks data (history : 3 years). An application displays the data. I change the configuration by default in postgres to improve the import of data.

**Everyday the table is refresh only with the current week, so the script deletes the current week and import the current week in the table.**
It takes 40 minutes but I think I could improve this.
If I truncate the entire table and import all the data, it tooks 3 hours (7 gigas).

**Is there a better way than the delete/insert ?**

I could create another table with only the data of the current week and use in the application "union" 
    select * from tb_data union all select * from tb_data_week
I think it will be faster because a truncate/insert on the data week table will be faster than the delete/insert in the big table. 
But it will be maybe slowly with the union all in the application

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could [partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) the table by week.

To import the weekly data, insert into a new empty table. Once the import is finished, drop the old week partition and attach the new partition using `alter table base_table attach partition ...`

The manual has an example for this process: [Partition Maintenance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-MAINTENANCE)